# Understanding Server-sent Events

Tags: java, html, server-sent-events

I'm trying to update an HTML5 table in real-time with some data from the database. Here is my code:

HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //check for browser support
    if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined") {
        //create an object, passing it the name and location of the server side script
        var eSource = new EventSource("[some address]/api/sse");
        //detect message receipt
        eSource.onmessage = function(event) {
            //write the received data to the page

            document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=table;

        };
    }
    else {
        [erro message]
    }
</script>
```

And my Java Restful service:

```
@Path("/sse")
   public class SSEResource {
   @Context
   private UriInfo context;

   public SSEResource() {
   }

   @GET
   @Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
   public String getServerSentEvents() throws Exception {

       SomeObject o = new SomeObject();     
       final String myString = o.someQuery().getEntity().toString();    

       return "data: " + myString + "\n\n";
   }
}
```

This `someQuery()` method queries from database and returns what I want to put on my table. Everythings looks great. But I want to know if it's right or wrong, because if I put some log on `someQuery()` method, I see that every 3 seconds the query is executed. This may cause heavy duty, right? Is this normal or is my code wrong?